# Expression.Invoke - What does it do?

Tags: c#, expression

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170.aspx

I could not understand what that class is for if it does not have the ruslt of the delegate I want to invoke..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Expression.Invoke` doesn't immediately invoke the given expression - it creates an expression tree *representing the invocation* of the given expression. That's what [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) are all about.

If you want to actually *execute* an expression tree, you need to build a `LambdaExpression`, call [`Compile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928.aspx) on it (which will build a delegate) and then invoke the delegate.